# Flume - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when integrating with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Trying to dump a small csv data into Kafka using Flume, I constantly got the error below no matter what input or configuration I tried when running "flume-ng avro-client -H localhost -p 4141 -F test_all_num.csv":

[image]

The flume agent seemed to start successfully when I ran "flume-ng agent -f kafkaSink.flm -n a1 -c /usr/local/Cellar/flume/1.9.0_1/libexec/conf".

[image]

test_all_num.csv is a small csv file consisting of 46 lines of numbers separated by comma.

Below is the screenshot of my configuration file for the flume agent:
[image]

I tried adding the limits of capacity for the channels (a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000, a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100) but that did not work.

Editing JAVA_OPTS in flume-env.sh was also tried but did not seem to work. Below is the screenshot of the flume-env.sh file:
[image]

Currently I am a bit stuck. Does anyone have any suggestion for this issue? Any help or pointer will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Flume development is basically halted. Try Kafka Connect - https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-spooldir/

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked. Thanks!